# Replace sub string in a string with specific value jQuery

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Hi Please help me to replace the sub string of following url using jquery. the following url have '/s320', in this sub string '/s' is will be constant but after '/s' numeric value '320' or '200' or any other numeric value, this numeric value may varies.

Now i want to replace '/s***(3 digit any numeric value)' to '/s1600'

**Input Strings:**
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-dPyWTw6OQG0/UiS1RsEKwcI/AAAAAAAAC10/_Uo_pFHExhw**/s320**/Pawan+Kalyan+Birthday+Special+Latest+Posters++(2).jpg

> **/s320** : this may be /200 or /100 or any numeric value of length = 3

**Output Stings**
i want this url for above urls.

> http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-dPyWTw6OQG0/UiS1RsEKwcI/AAAAAAAAC10/_Uo_pFHExhw/**s1600**/Pawan+Kalyan+Birthday+Special+Latest+Posters++(2).jpg

Comment: Did you try something ? This looks like a very regex

Comment: i have tried in jQuery not in regex

Comment: Where does jQuery enter this problem (I removed the tag which seemed useless) ?

Comment: Like @dystroy said, did you try anything? If so, show us what you've tried.

Comment: i have tried this :  '/s' found using match method if found after /s 3 digits are numeric or not then i have replaced with /s1600.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like regex you can use split and substr

```
function replaceParam(x){
    var i = x.indexOf("/s");
    return x.slice(0,i) + "/s1600" + x.substr(i+5);
}
replaceParam("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-dPyWTw6OQG0/UiS1RsEKwcI/AAAAAAAAC10/_Uo_pFHExhw/s320/Pawan+Kalyan+Birthday+Special+Latest+Posters++(2).jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
str = str.replace(/\/s\d+\//, "/s1600/")
```

References :

- [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: i have tried this its not working. please give me some other code.